# Вылетает эмулятор в Android Studio

Tags: android

ошибки: Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed: INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK

List of apks:
[0] 'E:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\TraficLight\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk'
The application's minSdkVersion is newer than the device API level.
[вот что выдает](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59R2n.png)
и вот [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: попробуйте повысить версию sdk при билде скорее всего там устаревшая версия не совместимая с версией в эмуляторе

Comment: Наоборот, там написано что минимальная версия (`minSdkVersion`) у приложения выше чем версия системы в эмуляторе